# reverse asp.net grid view columns header into rows header

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm still learning asp.net and I want to ask you about how to reverse the grid view, I mean the default grid view would be like this

[image: grid view with columns header]

and this is the code for it:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="256px">
        <Columns>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="1"> <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="test1" runat="server" Text="test1"></asp:Label>
                         </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="2"> <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="test2" runat="server" Text="test2"></asp:Label>
                         </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="3"> <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="test3" runat="server" Text="test3"></asp:Label>
                         </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>  </Columns>
        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

and i want it to be like this picture :

[image]

the test here will be data bound and the numbers should be header text, this is only for test, is there a way to reverse it?

thank you all for your valuable advises and efforts, I really appreciate it.

Comment: It seems as if you should use a `DataList` instead which supports the [`RepeatDirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatdirection(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I want by pivoting the data table and the columns became rows and the opposite.

this [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/05/10/pivot-data-in-gridview---a-generic-pivot-method-with.aspx) can explain it.

thx